# login.OAuthLogin(missing saved state) - Community version of grafana with OKTA integration

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to configure Community edition Grafana(official docker image) with Okta integration.

After doing Okta configuration, Okta authenticates and redirect request to grafana, where I hosted it,
But, it shows following error:

```
login.OAuthLogin(missing saved state)
```

I'm not using any database for storing sessions. I want to save it on local file only.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which had to do with the 'email' attribute not being available to Grafana.

- Make sure that 'api_url' contains 'email'.
- In Grafana OAuth config, set the following:

  - email_attribute_path
  - email_attribute_name

Example:

```
[auth.generic_oauth]    
email_attribute_path=email    
email_attribute_name=email
```

Example Grafana Configuration containing these properties can be found here: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/v6.4.0/conf/sample.ini

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response, I found detailed help at: https://www.gyanblog.com/gyan/how-configure-grafana-dashboard-oauth-okta-ssl-docker-nginx/